# Finding a Radom-Nikodym derivative

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f_1,f_2\in L^1(\mu)$ and consider the signed measures $$v_i(E):=\int_Ef_id\mu$$

for every $E\in\Sigma$.

If $v_1\ll v_2$ and $v_2\ll v_1$, we must find $\dfrac{dv_1}{dv_2}$.

First, I don't understand something. As states in Real Analysis (Folland), the Radon-Nikodym derivative exists when the signed measure in "denominator" is actually a measure. And of course $v_2$ need not be a measure. Is this ok?

Anyways. Let $g:=\dfrac{dv_1}{dv_2}$, so $g$ is the unique $v_2$-a.e. function such that $v_1(E)=\displaystyle\int_Egdv_2$ (again, I don't know if this integral makes sense if $v_2$ is not a measure) for every $E\in \Sigma$.

Then $$\int_Ef_1d\mu=\displaystyle\int_Egdv_2$$

for every $E\in\Sigma$.

Can anyone give my a hint in order to find $g$? It seems I'm very lost.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Radon-Nikodym theorem remains true even if on $(X,\Sigma,\nu_1)$ $\nu_1$ is a signed measure. (see p.x. Halmos, 31. (4)) Halmos' hint: Consider the Hahn decomposition of $X=A\cup B$ with respect to $\nu_1$ and then apply separately the Radon-Nikodym theorem for $\nu_2$ an $\nu_1^+$ in $A$, and to $\nu_2$ and $\nu_1^-$ in $B$.